# Issues setting up SSL, keep getting "no valid, non-passphrase-protected keys given" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I obtained a security certificate on StartSSL.com and followed the steps on Heroku closely. I was given intermediate as well as root certificates.

I tried different methods to chain these files but I get this error (see screenshot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFGDp.jpg

How can I fix this error?

The files that I downloaded are:

```
ca.pem (root cert)
sub.class1.server.ca.pem (intermediate cert)
copy and pasted the private key as server.key
copy and pasted the certificate as server.orig.crt
There's also the ca-bundle.pem that I tried using but no luck
```

I just redownloaded all of the files and ran this "cat server.orig.crt sub.class1.server.ca.pem ca-bundle.pem > server.crt"
Then ran heroku certs:add server.crt server.key and I get this error

```
Unable to read server.crt file
```

Additionally, I just tried without any CAT and simply "heroku certs:add ca-bundle.pem server.key" and I get this error

```
No certificate given is a domain name certificate
```

Comment: maybe you have to specify that you want to use a password?

Comment: Your answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568922/heroku-sslendpoint-with-globalsign-extendedssl

Answer (score 9):

A pem encoded certificate chain suitable for installation on heroku should consist of, in order: site, intermediate, then root pem encoded certificates.

```
cat server.orig.crt sub.class1.server.ca.pem ca.pem > heroku.crt
```

It looks to me more like a problem with your private key -- you need to make sure the pem file isn't encrypted with a passphrase, and that it is the same key pair used to generate the cert.  The head of the private key will look like this if encrypted:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
...
```

instead of just:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICaQIBAAKBhACxlzv7H57F+vapTjqS9qdfDg20RjwFFU1B3yK8SqN7rX0jpjsW
H3B2lhCqKPWd2To2LoOolhnsFbr5qlKK3ep/nuUZfkx1aOIg4L0FgzbuCSJfKE5B
...
```

In the former case, run (linux, mac os):

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.unencrypted.key
```

and enter the passphrase when prompted. Then use server.unencrypted.key in the call to heroku to add the cert.