# Heroku ssl:endpoint with GlobalSign ExtendedSSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I have signed up for GlobalSign ExtendedSSL.

I just can't figure out how to add this to `ssl:endpoint` addon.

When I signed up for ExtendedSSL i had to generate CSR certificate, which has the following files:

- private-key.key
- www.domain.com_csr.pem

Once the sign was complete, GlobalSign gave me the following:

- SSL Certificate
- ExtendedSSL Intermediate Certificate
- Extended Validation Cross Certificate

I have combined SSL Certificate, ExtendedSSL Intermediate Certificate and Extended Validation Cross Certificate server.crt.
And I have copied private-key.key to server.key

When i try to add it to the add, i get:

```
$ heroku certs:add server.crt server.key --app myapp
Resolving trust chain... failed
! No valid, non-passphrase-protected keys given.
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 13):

I have found the answer.

The private key is password protected. You cannot add passworded keys to heroku. You can remove the password by running:

```
openssl rsa -in private-key.key -out private-key-new.key
```

And then run:

```
heroku certs:add server.crt private-key-new.key --app myapp
```

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear on the steps 

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#generate-private-key

Comment: Yes now the document includes this.